# Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression in custom sorting function comparator

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, comparator

I am making a custom sorting function as an excercise for uni.

```
package com.mycompany.sortowanie;
public interface Comp<T>{
     <T> boolean compare(T o1, T o2);
}
```

and

```
package com.mycompany.sortowanie;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MaszynaSortujaca<T> {
   public void sort(LinkedList<T> arr, Comp cmp) {
       for(int i = 0; i < arr.size()-1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.size()-i-1; j++) {
                if(cmp.compare(arr.get(j), arr.get(j+1))) {
                    T temp = arr.get(j);
                    arr.set(j, arr.get(j+1));
                    arr.set(j+1, temp);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Please ignore the bits of polish language in here. Whenever I try to use a function on some class it gives me "incompatible parameter types in lambda expression" compilation error, like this:

```
m.sort(p, (Person n1, Person n2) -> {return n1.getAge() < n2.getAge();});
```

I don't understand why they are considered incompatible parameter types and I don't know what to do at this stage.
Here is the code of the Person class in case anyone needs that:

```
package com.mycompany.sortowanie;

public class Person{
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem, the `compare()` method should not have its own `<T>` variable. Writing `<T>` there shadows the one from `Comp<T>`, creating a different type variable with the same name. Remove it:

```
public interface Comp<T> {
    boolean compare(T o1, T o2);
}
```

Second problem, in the `sort()` function `Comp cmp` is missing `<T>`. Make sure both the linked list and the comparator have `<T>` so there are no raw types:

```
public void sort(LinkedList<T> arr, Comp<T> cmp) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it made me understand a couple things better. Unfortunately I get the same compilation error on the line where sort gets called. I should point out it happens only when explicitly writing parameter types. If I don't do it it doesn't allow me to use Person::getAge() tho.

Comment: Hm, I dunno. It compiled for me when I fixed these two errors.

Comment: @AleksanderBarański it should work, see here: https://onlinegdb.com/l98XF5ftx